# Correlation in Pandas - AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, correlation, sklearn-pandas, stat

I am trying to read in a file, subset 2 rows and find the correlation between them.

```
dfCorrelation=pd.read_csv(filename)
df1 = dfCorrelation.loc[1] #to subset the first row
df2 = dfCorrelation.loc[2] #to subset the second row
print(df1.corr(df2))
```

Here is my code. It errors out saying AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Please attach the complete error code to your post

Comment: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'

This is all it says

Comment: OKay then you can give some information about df, like `dfCorreation.head()`

Comment: post whole traceback

Comment: The traceback is too long wont fit in comments. I'll try to play around and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: make sure your column is not object type they are float type

Comment: changing the column type worked. Thanks